# Is it possible to provide named parameters with a hash in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

How to do it correctly?

```perl6
> sub adding(:$first, :$second) { $first + $second }
> adding(second => 2, first => 1)
3
> my %param = second => 2, first => 1
{first => 1, second => 2}
> adding(%param)
Too many positionals passed; expected 0 arguments but got 1
  in sub adding at <unknown file> line 1
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a prefix `|` to `%param`

```perl6
adding( |%param )
```

This also works for positional arguments

```perl6
sub foo ( $bar, $baz ){ "$bar:$baz" }
my @args = 'a', 'b';
foo( @args ) # error
foo( |@args ) # "a:b"
```

Comment: For the record, there is a corresponding syntax in the function declaration. `sub foo(*%param) { ... }` takes any named arguments, and writes them into `%param`.